# How to check whether the current user has administrative privileges

Tags: c, windows, winapi

What Windows API function can I use to check to see if the current user running my application has administrative privileges?

Here are my OS details : WINDOWS XP, VISTA and WINDOWS 7
Language to be used : C

Comment: Do you mean if the currently logged on user is an administrator? if the current process is running with admin privileges?

Comment: What capabilities are you looking for? Install hardware? Software? Even administrator mode can have its possibilities restricted.

Comment: My aim is to install an application which has a "Windows Service" and "Dpinst.exe", where both needs an admin privilege. So at start of my application I need to check whether the system is in admin mode or not, and if it is not in admin mode, I want the application to display a message to the user to change to admin mode.

Comment: what if the service has a custom DACL that denies administrator controls? You need to properly report access denied error anyways.

Comment: Do the applications need administrative rights also or just the installation procedure?

Comment: my application includes windows service and it needs to call dpinst.exe, where both needs an admin mode to get installed. thats why I need to check for admin mode validation at the start of my application. and if the user is not in admin mode my application simply needs to display a window saying change to admin mode..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if the *user* has administrative privileges it does not mean *your program* does - it needs to be elevated. This can be done by the user explicitly asking to run it as an administrator, but usually it is requested by the program itself through a manifest that is embedded into the executable. Once the manifest asks for the privileges it is not optional - the program will not run until the user has approved it and supplied the password as necessary.

Comment: actually the question is not "how to detect the credentials under which an apllication is or will be running under" but "How to check whether the current user has administrative privileges."

Comment: @mox, if you check the comments under the question you'll see that what they really want is to run their program with administrator privileges all the time. The only reason for checking privilege levels is to throw up an error box, which Windows will do for you automatically.

Answer (score 2):

The Shell API has a function IsUserAnAdmin() that does this. No messing around with tokens required.